# CSS positioning issue with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position

I'm having a very strange CSS issue with my slider and IE. As you can see, the pagination is being displayed above the slider. However, in all other browsers it is being displayed at the bottom of the slider correctly. I cannot figure out why this is, and I have tried everything, hence why I am here. See for yourself:

http://matthewruddy.com/demo - any ideas?

Comment: I dont see a "slider" in any browser...

Comment: Sorry, there was only one image. Two now to demonstrate the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using either conditional comments to place it for IE or using a js plugin like this one - http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the issue at all.

Comment: If the issue is only in IE browsers, then he could place the element in this matter to 'fix' it in IE.  It's not the ideal answer, but it is a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however with other themes the pagination displays correctly across all browsers. This issue is only present in IE with this particular theme, hence applying an IE only stylesheet or conditional element isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

There's a JS error: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Comment: Would this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @matthew: `$` is sually a shorthand in a js lib (jquery, prototype, etc..). Since it works in other browsers im going to guess that you have extra commas in a hash somewhere.. perhaps in your config for the slider for example this will not work in IE `{var1: value, var2: value,}` notice the extra trailing comma.

Comment: I don't understand how this would reposition the pagination? In all other themes, the pagination appears correctly across all browsers, however with this theme in IE it is presenting this problem.